# Offline plot.ly won't work from jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly

I'm trying to get started with plot.ly (python api) with this code that I'm running from a jupyter notebook:

```
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Javascript error adding output!
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: requirejs
See your browser Javascript console for more details.
```

I've opened js console and I'm seeing these errors:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have already installed plotly using `$ pip install plotly` the following should be sufficient to get you started. This is currently working in my Jupyter Notebook to plot offline.

```
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

py.init_notebook_mode(connected=True) # Initialise offline ploytly environment
```

Follow along with one of their simple [scatter plots](https://plot.ly/python/line-and-scatter/) to check everything is working. using `py.iplot` will display the plot as an output within your notebook, while `py.plot` will display the plot in a new tab.

Comment: just realized that this solution works in jupyter notebook but not in jupyter lab :(

Comment: Possibly try the recommendation [here](https://community.plot.ly/t/plots-not-showing-up-in-jupyter-lab-plotly-3-0/11542/7)